# Does a "flash precedence priority" really exist in the USA at a time of crisis or terrorism?

Tags: sudden-death

Powers Booth and his goons hold the Vice President of the USA, other high ranking VIPs & security staff, hostages at gunpoint.

He demands that the VP call the POTUS such that some "emergency" bank account transfers be made. The Vice President makes the argument that such transactions are impossible within the time frame requested, due to protocols bureaucracy etc.

Powers counters him saying that the POTUS will initiate the so called "flash precedence priority" such that things will begin rolling (leading us to believe that Powers has inside knowledge on how US agencies operate). Is this actually true? Can such a thing be done?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_precedence